# How to fit a Bootstrap4 card into a container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to fit a Bootstrap card's height into a container with a fixed height. I tried to use the conventaional rules of max-height, and so on, but no luck.

Please have a look in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/263168/

Copying the code here too:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col wrapper">
       <div class="card bootstrap-card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/560x560" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 60vh;
}

.bootstrap-card {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use `min-height` instead.

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 60vh;
}

.bootstrap-card {
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/zJxfHOZynf

Comment: Thanks Zim. But if I use min-height, the container's height will no longer be 60vh. It will fit to wrap the card which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

just answering my own question for the benefit of others. 
So it seems that CSS isn't capable of "squishing" elements into a container. I thought it was possible since you can fit an image inside a container, giving it max-height:100%.

Anyway, what is possible to do here is to limit the height of the image to say 65vh, and then you can use auto-margins such as margin-top to the other elements, to push them down to the bottom of the container